# how to store the value to the redux in react native

Tags: react-native, react-redux

i have get the value from previous page.so i have store the value into the redux store

```
    const food = this.props.navigation.getParam('food', "no data");
    const amount = this.props.navigation.getParam('amount', "data");
```

Comment: We need a little more info in order to help you. Have you successfully stored the data in redux? If so, then you'll need to: 1) *Register* your component with Redux (if using react native navigation), 2) `connect` your component to redux in the component module, 3) `mapStateToProps` so that you can which parts of your redux state your component can see. That data will then be available to the component through `this.props.whateverYouCallYourProp`. This basic example might be useful: https://redux.js.org/basics/example/  How much of this have you done? Are you using a package for navigation?

Comment: yes, i have use the react navigation package ,but i have little bit confused for have can store the value to the redux store

Comment: So if this is your first time, it will seem like there's a lot of work to store a value in redux. Honestly I think it's easier if you watch a youtube tutorial to walk you through it, because it's quite an involved process. If I explain it all in words it probably won't make a lot of sense! Maybe this will help make it clear: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KcC8KZ_Ga2M